# Test for uniform convergence on $\sum_{k=0}^\infty(\frac{1}{kx+2}-\frac{1}{(k+1)x+2})$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

Test for uniform convergence on $0 \le x \le 1$:
$$
\sum_{k = 0}^{\infty}
\left[{1 \over kx + 2} - {1 \over \left(k + 1\right)x + 2}\right]
$$
I think I'm supposed to use the weierstrass m-test. The subtraction between the two fractions are throwing me off but so far I set
$$
\lim_{n \to \infty}{\rm S}_{n}\left(x\right)
=\lim_{n \to \infty}
\left[{1 \over kx + 2} - {1 \over \left(k + 1\right)x + 2}\right]
$$
Would I be on the right path by doing this ?.
$$
\lim_{n \to \infty}
\left[{1 \over kx + 2} - {1 \over \left(k + 1\right)x + 2}\right]
\le \lim_{n\to\infty}\left({1 \over k} - {1 \over k + 1}\right)
$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that

$$S_n(x)=\sum_{k=0}^n\left(\frac{1}{kx+2}-\frac{1}{(k+1)x+2}\right)=\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{(n+1)x+2},$$

Hence, $S_n(x) \rightarrow 1/2$ for $x > 0$ and $S_n(x) \rightarrow 0$ for $x = 0$.

Since the limit function is discontinuous, the convergence is not uniform on $[0,1]$.